# Silverlight: DateTime format in TextBlocks

Tags: silverlight, xaml, datetime, string-formatting

I'd like to use a custom DateTimeFormat across my entire Silverlight app, so I plugged in the following code in my `App.xaml.cs`.

```
var ci = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
ci.DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormatInfo()
{
    ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy",
    LongDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy",
    FullDateTimePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HHmm\\h",
    AMDesignator = string.Empty,
    PMDesignator = string.Empty,
    ShortTimePattern = "HHmm\\h",
    LongTimePattern = "HHmm\\h"
};
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

A `DateTime.Now.ToString("f")` gives me the answer I want (which is a 24-hour format DateTime string). However, when I do the following in XAML, the TextBlock ignores my `CultureInfo` and does its own thing:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ArrivalTime,StringFormat=f}"/>
```

Does anybody know a way in which I can get the `TextBlock` to display in the format I desire? Many thanks...

Comment: try: Text="{Binding ArrivalTime, StringFormat={}{0:f}}"

Comment: Doesn't work, tried `Text="{Binding ArrivalTime, StringFormat=\{0:f\}}` too... no breakthrough.